# Why file is not created in /etc/ directory

Tags: c++, linux, c++11

Please find the code sample

```
void createFile(const std::string& FileName, const std::string& Content)
{
    ofstream of(FileName.c_str());
    of<<Content;
    of.close();
}
const std::string testFile = "/etc/testFile";
const std::string EmptyContent = "";
createFile(testFile, EmptyContent);
```

File is not creating at /etc/ directory. I think this is related to permissions. What extra I have to add in the code to work.

Comment: *I think this is related to permissions.* => Do you get any error when executing the program? And if you do, what is it? If you don't... you might want to read on how to handle stream errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing extra that you can add to this program to "make it work". If an arbitrary program can write to `/etc`, this would toss the traditional POSIX security model out the window.

In order to be able to write to `/etc`, your program must be executed as root.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a permission issue. Try to run your program using sudo:

```
sudo yourprogram
```